# React Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am having an `npm run build` error. I didn't get this error on localhost, I got the error while deploying my .NetCore React app. I ran an `npm update` but that didn't fix anything. Could I please no what's failing here?

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "InfrastructureConnect",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@progress/kendo-react-dialogs": "^2.8.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "swagger-ui": "^3.44.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get after I run `npm run build`:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! InfrastructureConnect@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the InfrastructureConnect@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhiredd\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-10T21_51_45_254Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try using [`swagger-ui-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-react) instead of `swagger-ui`.

Comment: Could be due to your local machine is running of of storage in Docker, try to clean unused images and run build again.

Comment: @Helen Tried swagger-ui-react. Same error msg, now it says ./node_modules/swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css, but the rest of its the same.

Comment: @Kyle.Ng well, I am just doing npm run build, and thats failing too, irrespective of deploying

Comment: I am having this issue too. my swagger-ui-react version is ^3.29.0 and using webpack. anybody did fix this issue before?

Comment: @development-ninja Its been a while, but I did manage to fix it myself.
I just answered the question. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts to solve this, here's a few things that fixed it:

**Package.json:**

"swagger-ui": "^3.52.2"

Some sort of swagger component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SwaggerUi, { presets } from 'swagger-ui';
import 'swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.css';

class SwaggerHelp extends Component {
  displayName = SwaggerHelp.name;

  componentDidMount() {
    SwaggerUi({
      dom_id: '#swaggerContainer',
      url: `/swagger/v1/swagger.json`,
      presets: [presets.apis],
      docExpansion: 'none',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="swaggerContainer" />
    );
  }
}

export default SwaggerHelp;
```

Hopefully, this helps.